# How to get get selected node id - Js Tree ContextMenu

Tags: d3.js, contextmenu, uipageviewcontroller, servicenow, d3tree

This is my code:
**When clicked on Open ( need to display on Which Node Open is Selected )** 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRMO9.png)

d3.contextMenu = function (menu, openCallback) {

```
// create the div element that will hold the context menu
d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').data([1])
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'd3-context-menu');

// close menu
d3.select('body').on('click.d3-context-menu', function() {
    d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
});

// this gets executed when a contextmenu event occurs
return function(data, index) {
    var elm = this;

    d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').html('');
    var list = d3.selectAll('.d3-context-menu').append('ul');
    list.selectAll('li').data(menu).enter()
        .append('li')
        .html(function(d) {
            return (typeof d.title === 'string') ? d.title : d.title(data);
        })
        .on('click', function(d, i) {
            d.action(elm, data, index);
            d3.select('.d3-context-menu').style('display', 'none');
        });

    // the openCallback allows an action to fire before the menu is displayed
    // an example usage would be closing a tooltip
    if (openCallback) {
        if (openCallback(data, index) === false) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // display context menu
    d3.select('.d3-context-menu')
        .style('left', (d3.event.pageX - 2) + 'px')
        .style('top', (d3.event.pageY - 2) + 'px')
        .style('display', 'block');

    d3.event.preventDefault();
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
};
```

};

```
    var menu = [
{
    title: ' Open',
    action: function(elm, d, i) {

        **alert(selected Node Id );**

    }
}
```

];

**BMAGE BELOW OF THE js Tree** need to display on which node open is Clicked.